# Trying to use geoJSON , but coordinates looks strange?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Im trying to draw vectors on my OpenLayers map with a geoJSON that i have created myself.

In my databse i store Longitude and latitude:

```
Latitude: 59.125226
Longitude: 15.996094
```

These however does not work, in the example code from OpenLayers the coordinates looks something like this:

```
[[[-5e6, 6e6], [-5e6, 8e6], [-3e6, 8e6], [-3e6, 6e6]]],
[[[-2e6, 6e6], [-2e6, 8e6], [0, 8e6], [0, 6e6]]],
[[[1e6, 6e6], [1e6, 8e6], [3e6, 8e6], [3e6, 6e6]]]
```

My coordinates right now does not work, this is what i've tried but the "point" still shows in the center of the map, i guess at 0,0 ?

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
   "type": "Point",
   "coordinates":  [ 15.996094,59.125226 ]
}
}
]
}
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to plot lat/lon coordinates on a non lat/lon map.  Most commercial maps use EPSG:3857 projection (which is in meters) so ol is placing your feature at 15,59 meters from 0,0.

There are a number of ways to transform input, but it's not clear how you are getting the data.  To simply transform a coordinate in some in-line GeoJSON, you can use the following:

```
   coordinates: ol.proj.transform([15.996094,59.125226], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
```